# mergeOptions changes not reflected

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm trying to get a badge to display on one of the navigation tabs.

```js
onClickSetBadge() {
    console.log('Button pressed!')
    Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
      bottomTab: {
        badge: `TeSt`
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm calling it inside the view I'm rendering.

```js
<ButtonView text='SUP' onPress={() => {this.onClickSetBadge()}} />
```

The log statement shows up in my console, however, the badge is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official document: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/layout-types?id=updating-options-for-a-specific-tab , that is how it works:

1) Define an id for the specific tab:

```
    stack: {
      id: 'CartTab',
      children: [{
        component: {
          name: 'store-cart',
        }
      }],
      options: {
        bottomTab: {
          text: 'Cart',
          icon: require('../asset/image/menu/cart.png'),
        }
      }
    }
```

2) Use the tab id to update when needed:

```
  Navigation.mergeOptions('CartTab', {
    bottomTab: {
      badge: cart.length > 0 ? cart.length.toString() : ''
    }
  });
```